# Is nice ignoring aliases?

Tags: bash, shell, alias, nice

I have `alias rm='rm -i'` in my `~/.bashrc` file (I've just learned it is [considered bad practice](https://superuser.com/questions/384769/alias-rm-rm-i-considered-harmful) by some).

It seems the alias is not taken into account when running it with `nice`:

```
bli@naples:~$ touch test
bli@naples:~$ rm test
rm: remove regular empty file 'test'? n
bli@naples:~$ nice rm test
bli@naples:~$
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `nice` is an external command:

```
$ command -v nice
/usr/bin/nice
```

This means it has no knowledge of aliases, which are a shell feature:

```
$ alias foo='echo hello'
$ foo
hello
$ nice foo
nice: foo: No such file or directory
```

However there is a feature of the shell that allows aliases to *also* expand further aliases.  You end the expansion with a space.

```
$ alias nice='/usr/bin/nice '
```

Spot that space at the end; it's important.

Now...

```
$ nice foo
hello
$ command -v nice
alias nice='/usr/bin/nice '
```

Any external command can be wrapped with an alias like this if you want the shell to do alias expansion.

Answer (score 2):

`nice` is not `bash`. `bash` substitutes the aliases while `nice` doesn't. Using aliases is a bash-only feature. And zsh, ksh, ...so: shell feature. `nice` is not a shell.

Answer (score 2):

`nice` will use one of the `exec(3)` system calls, which know nothing about shell aliases. Global alias replacement can be done in some shells (e.g. ZSH) though I consider it such a massive footgun that I only mention it as a warning to the next 10 generations:

```
% alias -g rm='rm -i'
% echo hi rm there
hi rm -i there
%
```